# Jetty Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysema/query/dml/UpdateClause

Tags: jetty

I run

```
mvn jetty:run-war
```

See this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysema/query/dml/UpdateClause
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2436)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:1937)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.annotations.AnnotationFinder$ParsedMethod.toMethod(AnnotationFinder.java:360)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.annotations.AnnotationFinder.getMethodsForAnnotation(AnnotationFinder.java:678)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.annotations.AnnotationProcessor.processPostConstructAnnotations(AnnotationProcessor.java:303)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.annotations.AnnotationProcessor.processLifeCycleCallbackAnnotations(AnnotationProcessor.java:295)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.annotations.AnnotationProcessor.process(AnnotationProcessor.java:110)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.annotations.Configuration.parseAnnotations(Configuration.java:138)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6MavenConfiguration.parseAnnotations(Jetty6MavenConfiguration.java:121)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.AbstractConfiguration.configure(AbstractConfiguration.java:121)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configureWebApp(WebXmlConfiguration.java:229)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.AbstractConfiguration.configureWebApp(AbstractConfiguration.java:98)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.Configuration.configureWebApp(Configuration.java:149)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1212)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:548)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:348)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.doStart(Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.java:107)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:151)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:151)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginServer.start(Jetty6PluginServer.java:132)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:384)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:320)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6RunWar.execute(Jetty6RunWar.java:67)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysema.query.dml.UpdateClause
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:326)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:279)
        ... 52 more
2013-04-02 12:07:44.209::INFO:  Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
```

POM is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.rbs.prototypeweb</groupId>
        <artifactId>stylesuite</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.rbs.prototypeweb</groupId>
    <artifactId>stylesuite.ui</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>stylesuite.ui</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>sms</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- As we are doing "inplace" GWT compilation, ensure the widgetset -->
            <!-- directory is cleaned properly -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets</directory>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512M -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs>
                    <webappDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets
                    </webappDirectory>
                    <hostedWebapp>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets
                    </hostedWebapp>
                    <noServer>true</noServer>
                    <!-- Remove draftCompile when project is ready -->
                    <draftCompile>true</draftCompile>
                    <compileReport>true</compileReport>
                    <style>OBF</style>
                    <strict>true</strict>
                    <runTarget>http://localhost:8080/</runTarget>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- if you don't specify any modules, the plugin will find them -->
                            <!-- <modules> <module>com.vaadin.demo.mobilemail.gwt.ColorPickerWidgetSet</module> 
                                </modules> -->
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>resources</goal>
                            <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-jetty</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                            <daemon>true</daemon>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop-jetty</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-client</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiled</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-shared</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.data.jpa.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>${junit.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.16</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>   

            <!-- HSQL -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
                <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
                <version>${hsql.version}</version>
            </dependency>       

            <!-- H2 -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                <version>${h2.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
                <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
                <version>${jodatime.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>       

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin.addon</groupId>
                <artifactId>jpacontainer</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0.beta1</version>
            </dependency>   


    </dependencies>

</project>
```

It seems to work run ok on Tomcat. Also, when I look at the server output is says

> [INFO] Starting jetty 7.0.0.pre5 ...

which is a different jetty version to that defined in the plugin

Comment: The current jetty-7 release is 7.6.10.v20130312.  That release was from before we even moved to the eclipse foundation which was over 4 years ago now.  We are releasing jetty-9 now...

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to the POM seems to fix it:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.mysema.commons</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysema-commons-jetty</artifactId>
   <version>6.1.15</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be old, but this solution worked for me. Adding this to POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.3</version>
</dependency>
```